# How do you fix the n+1 queries problem in ActiveRecord (Rails 3) when also using the after_initialize callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles 
  after_initialize :add_user_roles

  def add_user_roles
    UserRoles.all.each do |ur|
      self.user_roles << ur unless self.user_roles.include?(ur)
    end
  end
end
```

Statement that finds the projects:

```
@projects = Project.includes(:user_roles)
```

So you can see, I'm telling it to include the user roles association in the query. However, I'm still seeing the n+1 queries problem: it finds the roles once for each project.

If I remove the usage of `self.user_roles` from the callback and look at the logs, I can see it finds the projects and their user roles in 2 queries - one for the projects, and one for the roles using `project_id in (1,2,3,4,5...,n)`.

Is there a way to work around this?

Let me clarify a bit: While I'm willing to work around my specific situation if required, I'd much prefer answers that focused on how to fix the problem in general. I am capable of writing a kludge to get the data in the state that I want it without using the after_initialize callback, and hence not coming into the n+1 queries problem. However, I would rather not do that, so I prefer answers to the general problem as opposed to my specific example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even eager-loaded associations aren't available in `after_initialize` (they get loaded *after* the record is initialized). See this Rails issue for some discussion:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13156

Related to the original question: it looks like every project will have the same set of `UserRole` objects. I'm guessing there's a `has_many :through` that's been sanitized out, but even so, how does a `Project` ever wind up not having the full set? I'm not seeing how `Project` and `UserRole` are actually connected here - from what's visible in the example, this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  def user_roles
    UserRole.all
  end
end
```

would accomplish the same thing as the `after_initialize`...

Comment: It's been long enough that I don't remember the *why*. I think it may be because the roles were a system-wide model that could be copied into a Project, and the names changed there, so yeah there's a HABTM probably missing which reflects that.

Comment: In any case, since there is a Rails issue mentioning it, and it looks like it won't be "fixed," I'll accept this as the right answer: not possible.

Answer (score 6):

take a look at rails eager loading 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

you can load association while loading object using `includes`

```
User.find(2).includes(:assets)#will load all assets with user
```

or you can specify in model to eager load association

app/models/user.rb

```
class User< AR::Base
   has_many :posts,:include=>:comments
end

class Post < AR::Base
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :user
end
```

now `u.posts` will load comments for each post

Comment: Hi Naveed, in the original question, I mentioned I am already using eager loadin, and in fact there is a line in there that uses the includes method. (`Project.includes(:user_roles)`) The issue is not eager loading - it's eager loading while also using `after_initialize`. Do you have a way to fix that?

Comment: Hi,First of all nature of `UserRole` is not suitable in  `after_initialize` callback because its called every time an Object of user is initiated.best place for this callback is `before_save,after_save,or after_create`.. right now you are if you call `User.all' then, `add_user_roles` will be called for each user which is again query form database to load user roles. with that i suggest move `add_user_roles` to before save  then eager load will work fine.

Comment: I appreciate what you are saying, but could you imagine anyone in any situation wanting to use after_initialize while also eager-loading associations? Such a suggestion would not help them. In the situation that prompted the question, we really did not want to run it on a save activity, because saving was a rare occurrence, and  because if there had been new roles added to the system, all projects needed to reflect that the next time they were loaded.

Comment: So we could say either "when a new role is added to the system, update every project" or we could just say "only update projects as they are accessed." The better solution IMO is the lazy one in that case, except that Rails would not conform to our wishes to eager load the associations.

Comment: Has anyone tested this? I don't think you can call 'includes' or 'joins' on an instantiated object. This should be: User.includes(:assets).find(2)

Answer (score 1):

This is likely caused by the after_initialize callback, which is run every time each of the objects are initialized. If the point of the callback is to automatically assign every role to every user (unless already assigned), then you could do this via a `before_save` filter instead. That way, the code won't run when doing your `Project.includes(:user_roles)` finder.

Comment: I chose after_initialize instead of before_save purposefully because I want the projects to get new roles in the DB if they don't have them, even if the projects are never saved again. For instance, if a new role pops up in the system, existing projects should automatically have that role the next time they are queried from the DB. Does that make sense?